# Limiting resultset using @Query anotations

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I have a query where I want to limit the size of the resultset.  As JPA does not support 'LIMIT', I have been trying to work out the correct approach.  I have tried:

```
@Query("SELECT w FROM WardTransaction w WHERE w.visit = :visit ORDER BY w.admissionDateTime DESC").setMaxResults(1)
public WardTransaction findCurrent(@Param("visit") Visit visit);
```

Which is not correct.  I am just looking for some guidance as to the correct syntax.

My repository code is:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Query("SELECT w FROM WardTransaction w WHERE w.visit = :visit ORDER BY w.admissionDateTime DESC")
```

The above is the query method definition, to setMaxResult in your query you need to use Pageable object as it follows.

```
    @Query("SELECT w FROM WardTransaction w WHERE w.visit = :visit ORDER BY w.admissionDateTime DESC")
public void List<Entities> findAll(Pageable pageable)
```

JPA repository must implement [SimpleJpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html)

Set Pageable object as it follows>

```
    Pageable pageSpecification = PageRequest(int page, int size)
```

Combination for Pageable and SimpleJpaRepository is the solution.

Take a look [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-seven-pagination/)

If you are using EntityManager and NamedQueries, there is a method setMaxResult that apply to Query object, but it is a different story.

Comment: Actually, I have a repository class - I am not sure if this helps?  I will have a look at the reference..

Comment: Yes, you are applying the @Query above the method,try to change with my recomendation of SimpleJpa and Pageable